# Unhandled rejection Error: A required argument is missing

Tags: node.js

so I was using this file called **revertranks.js** and I tried to run it with **node revertranks.js**.

When I run it, there would be this error saying the following:

"Unhandled rejection Error: A required argument is missing"

I was wondering why this was happening so I was checking this website and tried other solutions, however, none worked. One which made the error go away actually just made the code stop.

Here is the code:

```
 * About:
 * Reverts all rank change actions of a group after a specified date, with the option to filter by user.
 */

// Settings
const cookie = process.env.Cookie || '' // Roblox account .ROBLOSECURITY cookie
const options = {
  group: (process.env.GroupId), // Group ID
  userId: (process.env.AA1), // Revert rank changes made by this specified user - NOTE: When <= 0 any rank changes will be reverted
  afterDate: new Date('2021-01-01 00:00 CDT') // Date after which any rank changes will be reverted
}

// Dependencies
const rbx = require('noblox.js')
const logUpdate = require('log-update')

// Main
let scanning = true
const logItems = {
  scanned: 0,
  filtered: 0,
  reverted: 0,
  failed: 0
}

async function getAuditLogPage (getAuditLogOptions, cursor) {
  getAuditLogOptions.cursor = cursor || ''

  const auditLogPage = await rbx.getAuditLog(getAuditLogOptions)

  return auditLogPage
}

function filterAuditLogItems (auditLogItems) {
  const filteredAuditLogItems = []

  for (const auditLogItem of auditLogItems) {
    if (Date.parse(auditLogItem.created) > options.afterDate) {
      logItems.filtered++
      filteredAuditLogItems.push(auditLogItem.description)
    }
  }

  return filteredAuditLogItems
}

async function revertAuditLogItems (auditLogItems) {
  for (const auditLogItem of auditLogItems) {
    const setRankOptions = {
      group: options.group,
      target: auditLogItem.TargetId,
      roleset: auditLogItem.OldRoleSetId
    }

    await rbx.setRank(setRankOptions)
      .then(() => {
        logItems.reverted++
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        logItems.failed++
      })
  }
}

rbx.setCookie(process.env.Cookie)
  .then(async () => {
    console.time('Time taken')

    const logUpdater = setInterval(() => {
      logUpdate(`Scanned: ${logItems.scanned}\nFiltered: ${logItems.filtered}\nReverted: ${logItems.reverted}\nFailed: ${logItems.failed}`)

      if (!scanning && logItems.reverted + logItems.failed === logItems.filtered) {
        clearInterval(logUpdater)

        console.timeEnd('Time taken')
      }
    }, 100)

    const getAuditLogOptions = {
      group: options.group,
      actionType: 'changeRank',
      userId: options.userId > 0 ? options.userId : null,
      limit: 100
    }

    let auditLogPage = await getAuditLogPage(getAuditLogOptions)
    logItems.scanned += auditLogPage.data.length

    await revertAuditLogItems(filterAuditLogItems(auditLogPage.data))

    while (auditLogPage.nextPageCursor !== null && Date.parse(auditLogPage.data[auditLogPage.data.length - 1].created) > options.afterDate) {
      auditLogPage = await getAuditLogPage(getAuditLogOptions, auditLogPage.nextPageCursor)
      logItems.scanned += auditLogPage.data.length

      await revertAuditLogItems(filterAuditLogItems(auditLogPage.data))
    }

    scanning = false
  
  })
```

Please help me, I need this to revert an action on a website using a bot.

Here is the error message since someone asked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHtAO.jpg

I apologize for the previous message, I put some of the code I was experimenting with.

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: I have added the error to the question.